# convert substrings to dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Looking for a elegant way to convert a list of substrings and the text between them to key, value pairs in a dict.  Example:

```
s = 'k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more'
key_list = ['k1','k2','k3']
(missing code)
# s_dict = {'k1':'some text', 'k2':'more text', 'k3':'and still more'}
```

This is solvable using `str.find()`, etc, but I know there's a better solution than what I've hacked together.

Comment: So, is the key going to be a word without spaces?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ consider them known from a list (sans `:`) - I've edited the code.

Comment: Hmm, it isn't going to be easy to figure out where one value ends and the next key begins with code.

Comment: `s = 'k1:some text k2:I was on the k1 once k3:and still more'` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner would like to parse as `{... k2:'I was on the k1 once' ...}`.  Still well defined if `:` is reserved syntax.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird You're looking for an elegant way - then exclude regex which is designed precisely for arbitrary complex pattern matching in strings?

Comment: I've rolled the edit back for now to maintain consistency. But you can always write a new question with your updated requirements. That should work!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Option 1**
If the keys don't have spaces or colons, you can simplify your solution with `dict` + `re.findall` (`import re`, first):

```
>>> dict(re.findall('(\S+):(.*?)(?=\s\S+:|$)', s))
{'k1': 'some text', 'k2': 'more text', 'k3': 'and still more'}
```

Only the placement of the colon (`:`) determines how keys/values are matched.

**Details**

```
(\S+)   # match the key (anything that is not a space)
:       # colon (not matched)
(.*?)   # non-greedy match - one or more characters - this matches the value 
(?=     # use lookahead to determine when to stop matching the value
\s      # space
\S+:    # anything that is not a space followed by a colon 
|       # regex OR
$)      # EOL
```

Note that this code assumes the structure as presented in the question. It will fail on strings with invalid structures.

---

**Option 2**
Look ma, no regex...
This operates on the same assumption as the one above.

1. Split on colon (`:`)
2. All elements but the first and last will need to be split again, on space (to separate keys and values)
3. zip adjacent elements, and convert to dictionary

```
v = s.split(':')
v[1:-1] = [j for i in v[1:-1] for j in i.rsplit(None, 1)]

dict(zip(v[::2], v[1::2]))
{'k1': 'some text', 'k2': 'more text', 'k3': 'and still more'}
```

Comment: impressive.  Does `regexp` still make your eyes bleed, or does it get better with time? :)

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird Regex has its moments. To play with fire, you'd either have to be a pyromaniac, or be ready to get burned. ;)

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird Added an option 2 for you.

Comment: this is pretty good!  I was hoping I could delimit by `key:` so a `:` in the value wouldn't throw things off...

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird That would need... dun dun dun... regex... unless you know the order in which your keys appear in the string?!

Comment: haha :)  I guess regex goes at the end of a very long list of things to do!

Comment: So I've refined this problem and the posted solution no longer works exactly (see string in question).  Can you update this answer?

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird I could but that would invalidate the other answers. IMO the best thing to do would be to write a new question and link this one to it saying the new question is an "extension" based on the new string given. Sounds good?

Answer (score 7):

If the keys don't have spaces or colons in it, you could:

- split according to alpha followed by colon to get the tokens
- zip half shifted slices in a dict comprehension to rebuild the dict

like this:

```
import re,itertools
s = 'k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more'
toks = [x for x in re.split("(\w+):",s) if x]  # we need to filter off empty tokens
# toks => ['k1', 'some text ', 'k2', 'more text ', 'k3', 'and still more']
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(itertools.islice(toks,None,None,2),itertools.islice(toks,1,None,2))}
print(d)
```

result:

```
{'k2': 'more text ', 'k1': 'some text ', 'k3': 'and still more'}
```

using `itertools.islice` avoids to create sub-lists like `toks[::2]` would do

Answer (score 5):

Another **regex** magic with splitting the input string on **key/value** pairs:

```
import re

s = 'k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more'
pat = re.compile(r'\s+(?=\w+:)')
result = dict(i.split(':') for i in pat.split(s))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'k1': 'some text', 'k2': 'more text', 'k3': 'and still more'}
```

---

- using `re.compile()` and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several times in a single program
- `\s+(?=\w+:)` - the crucial pattern to split the input string by whitespace character(s) `\s+` if it's followed by a *"key"*(a word `\w+` with colon `:`).
   `(?=...)` - stands for lookahead positive assertion

Comment: this is a very nice soln.  Thank you for the regex explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of your known keys (and maybe also values, but I don't address that in this answer), you can do it with a regex. There might be a shortcut if, say, you can simply assert that the last whitespace before a colon definitely signals the beginning of the key, but this should work as well:

```
import re

s = 'k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more'
key_list = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']
dict_splitter = re.compile(r'(?P<key>({keys})):(?P<val>.*?)(?=({keys})|$)'.format(keys=')|('.join(key_list)))
result = {match.group('key'): match.group('val') for match in dict_splitter.finditer(s)}
print(result)
>> {'k1': 'some text ', 'k2': 'more text ', 'k3': 'and still more'}
```

Explanantion:

```
(?P<key>({keys}))  # match all the defined keys, call that group 'key'
:                  # match a colon
(?P<val>.*?)       # match anything that follows and call it 'val', but
                   # only as much as necessary..
(?=({keys})|$)     # .. as long as whatever follows is either a new key or 
                   # the end of the string
.format(keys=')|('.join(key_list))
                   # build a string out of the keys where all the keys are
                   # 'or-chained' after one another, format it into the
                   # regex wherever {keys} appears.
```

**Caveat 1:** If your keys can contain each other order is important, and you might want to go from long keys to shorter ones in order to force longest matches first: `key_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True)`

**Caveat 2:** If your key list contains regex metacharacters, it will break the expression, so they might need to be escaped first: `key_list = [re.escape(key) for key in key_list]`

Answer (score 1):

This version is a bit more verbose but straightforward-ish, it doesn't require any library and takes `key_list` into account:

```
def substring_to_dict(text, keys, key_separator=':', block_separator=' '):
    s_dict = {}
    current_key = None

    for block in text.split(block_separator):
        if key_separator in block:
            key, word = block.split(key_separator, 1)
            if key in keys:
                current_key = key
                block = word
        if current_key:
            s_dict.setdefault(current_key, []).append(block)

    return {key:block_separator.join(s_dict[key]) for key in s_dict}
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> keys = {'k1','k2','k3'}
>>> substring_to_dict('k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more', keys)
{'k1': 'some text', 'k2': 'more text', 'k3': 'and still more'}
>>> substring_to_dict('k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more k4:not a key', keys)
{'k1': 'some text', 'k2': 'more text', 'k3': 'and still more k4:not a key'}
>>> substring_to_dict('', keys)
{}
>>> substring_to_dict('not_a_key:test', keys)
{}
>>> substring_to_dict('k1:k2:k3 k2:k3:k1', keys)
{'k1': 'k2:k3', 'k2': 'k3:k1'}
>>> substring_to_dict('k1>some;text;k2>more;text', keys, '>', ';')
{'k1': 'some;text', 'k2': 'more;text'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's a great idea, but for the sake of completeness it is also an option to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in this case:

```
from ast import literal_eval
s = 'k1:some text k2:more text k3:and still more'
key_list = ['k1','k2','k3']
s_ = s
for k in key_list:
            s_ = s_.replace('{}:'.format(k), '","{}": "'.format(k))

s_dict = literal_eval('{{{}"}}'.format(s_[2:]))

print(s_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'k1': 'some text ', 'k2': 'more text ', 'k3': 'and still more'}
```